# MariaDB Backup from the command line

Tags: swisscomdev

The Backup feature in the developer console for creating backups is great. I would however like the possibility to automate this. Is there a way to do so from the cf command line app?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible from the `cf cli`, but there's an [API endpoint](https://api.lyra-836.appcloud.swisscom.com/api-doc/#!/Service_Instances/post_custom_service_instances_service_instance_id_backups) for triggering backups.

> API Docs | Custom Extensions | Swisscom Application Cloud Filter for
>   Cloud Foundry (CF) Cloud Controller (CC) API. Implements Swisscom
>   proprietary extensions

```
POST /custom/service_instances/{service-instance-id}/backups
```

> Creates a backup for a given service instance

See for more Info [Service Backup and Restore](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide-sc/services/backups.html) in docs.developer.swisscom.com

> Create Backup To create a backup, navigate to the service instance in
>   the web console and then to the “Backups” tab. There you can click the
>   “Create” button to trigger a manual backup.
>
> Note: Backups have to be triggered manually from the web console.
>
> Be aware that you can only keep a set number of backups per service
>   instance. The actual number is dependent on the service type and
>   service plan. In case you already have the maximum number, you cannot
>   create any new backups before deleting one of the existing.
>
> It may take several minutes to backup your service (depending on the
>   size of your service instance).
>
> Restore Backup You can restore any backup at any time. The current
>   state of your backup will be overwritten and replaced with the state
>   saved to the backup. You are advised to create a backup of the current
>   state before restoring an old state.
>
> Limitations You can only perform one backup or restore action per
>   service instance at a time. If an action is still ongoing, you cannot
>   trigger another one. You cannot exceed the maxmimum number of backups
>   per service instance

Answer (score 2):

We did this by developing a small Node.js application which is running on the cloud in the same space and which backups our maria and mongo db every night automatically.

**EDIT:**
You can download the code from here:
https://github.com/theonlyandone/cf-backup-app

Comment: Nice idea. Would be nice if you had the possibility to share your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You create backups with the API provided by Swisscom, right? Have you also thought about "exporting" backups to another location (i.e. external backup server)?

Answer (score 2):

Fresh from the press: [Swisscom Application Cloud cf CLI Plugin](https://github.com/swisscom/appcloud-cf-cli-plugin) can also automate backup and restore.

> The official cf CLI plugin for the Swisscom Application Cloud gives
>   you access to all the additional features of the App Cloud.

```
cf install-plugin -r CF-Community "Swisscom Application Cloud"
```

from [0.1.0 release notes](https://github.com/swisscom/appcloud-cf-cli-plugin/releases/tag/v0.1.0)

> Service Instance Backups
>
> - Add `cf backups` command (list all backups of a service instance)
> - Add `cf create-backup` command (create a new backup of a service instance)
> - Add `cf restore-backup` command (restore an existing backup of a service instance)
> - Add `cf delete-backup` command (delete an existing backup of a service instance)

Answer (score 1):

Despite the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39702754/4783487) from [Matthias Winzeler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5488567/matthias-winzeler) saying it's not possible, in fact it's totally possible to automate MariaDB backups through the command line.

I developed a plugin for the CF CLI:
https://github.com/gsmachado/cf-mariadb-backup-plugin

In future I could extend such plugin to backup any kind of service that is supported by the Cloud Foundry Provider's API (in this case, [Swisscom AppCloud API](https://api.lyra-836.appcloud.swisscom.com/api-doc/#/Service_Instances)).

Comment: @kaktusgruen: I think my answer should be the accepted one, since I provided you a solution for your problem.